# Google Chrome extension "Cannot read property 'local' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

By doing:

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({"extension_file": extension_file}, function() {
    console.log('Value is set to ' + extension_file);
});
```

I see error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined
```

In manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage"
]
```

What should I do?

Comment: Seems like `chrome.storage` is undefined. Have you verified that you're importing everything you need correctly? Can you provide more context to your code?

Comment: The info is incomplete so I have to guess. Usually this error means your code is running outside of extension context. For example you've put it into a `script` element in a web page so it runs in the web page context. It can also mean you've disabled or reloaded your extension which made the old content scripts "orphaned", but you didn't unregister their DOM event listeners so they are still fired.

Answer (score 0):

You've updated your Manifest.json file, and you just need to tell Chrome to reload it so the "storage" permission can be applied.

Open a tab to chrome://extensions and click the reload button for your extension.